# How to Troubleshoot this apache2 failure of restart?

Tags: raspberry-pi, apache-httpd, raspbian, https

Condition: http://192.168.1.107/ and http://192.168.1.107/owncloud (with/without https) not alive after reconfiguring settings with self-signed SSL certifigates for HTTPS as described by the [thread](http://www.slsmk.com/enabling-https-access-to-owncloud/) where I followed all steps until the failure to restart `apache2`.
Support: failure to restart apache2

I do

```
# http://www.slsmk.com/enabling-https-access-to-owncloud/
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/owncloud-ssl.conf 

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ a2enconf owncloud-ssl.conf
Conf owncloud-ssl already enabled

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-06-22 21:34:31 UTC; 28min ago
  Process: 14965 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7474 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17524 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: Output of config test was:
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabl...onf:
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/ssl/certs/my-public-cert.pe...mpty
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Tue 2016-05-31 16:20:51 UTC, end at Wed 2016-06-22 22:06:09 UTC. --
Jun 22 21:41:03 raspberrypi sudo[17644]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by masi(uid=0)
Jun 22 21:41:51 raspberrypi sudo[17644]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 22 22:01:17 raspberrypi sudo[17801]: masi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/masi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journal
Jun 22 22:01:17 raspberrypi sudo[17801]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by masi(uid=0)
Jun 22 22:02:36 raspberrypi sudo[17801]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 22 22:02:38 raspberrypi sudo[17812]: masi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/masi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemc
Jun 22 22:02:38 raspberrypi sudo[17812]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by masi(uid=0)
Jun 22 22:02:38 raspberrypi sudo[17812]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 22 22:06:08 raspberrypi sudo[17829]: masi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/masi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journal
Jun 22 22:06:09 raspberrypi sudo[17829]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by masi(uid=0)
```

Settings

- My important config files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` are `000-default.conf` and `000-default-ssl.conf` where both have SSL configs; complete `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` at the end

  ```
  # 000-default.conf
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
  ```

  The other file just a symlink to the other by `ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

  ```
  total 8
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 22 15:32 .
  drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jun 22 21:41 ..
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   45 May 31 19:35 000-default.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 May 31 11:50 000-default-ssl.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
  ```
- `/etc/apache2/envvars` is alive and kicking ([thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/644970/25388))

  ```
  # https://askubuntu.com/a/718551/25388
  export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
  export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
  ```
- Keys made like

  ```
  # http://www.slsmk.com/enabling-https-access-to-owncloud/
  sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
  sudo mkdir /etc/ssl
  sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
      -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache.key \
      -out /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/apache.crt

  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244129/use-rsa-private-key-to-generate-public-key
  sudo -i
  openssl rsa -in /etc/ssl/private/apache.key -pubout \    
      > /etc/ssl/certs/my-pubkey.perm
  ```
- Owner/group of `/etc/ssl/`

  ```
  sudo ls -la /etc/ssl/ | grep certs
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 24576 Jun 22 13:13 certs

  sudo ls -la /etc/ssl/ | grep private 
  drwx--x---- 2 root ssl-cert 4096 Jun 22 13:11 private
  ```

I do

```
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl -l
  ... 
  session-c25.scope                                                           
● apache2.service                                                             
  avahi-daemon.service                                                        
  ...
  ssh.service                                                                 
● systemd-ask-password-console.service                                        
● systemd-ask-password-wall.service                                           
  systemd-fsck-root.service                                                   
  ...

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

116 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

I do

```
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl -l status apache2 
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-06-22 21:34:31 UTC; 22h ago

Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: Output of config test was:
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/owncloud-ssl.conf:
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/ssl/certs/my-public-cert.pem' does not exist or is empty
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi apache2[17524]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jun 22 21:34:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
```

I see `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.960434 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] AH02580: Init: Pass phrase incorrect for key localhost:80:0
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.960823 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.960922 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.961001 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.961085 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.961165 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.961242 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.961324 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.961363 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
[Fri Jun 24 06:37:41.961393 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3605] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key localhost:80:0, check /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445081 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] AH02580: Init: Pass phrase incorrect for key localhost:80:0
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445296 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445346 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445386 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445428 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445470 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445508 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445550 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445570 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:08.445586 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3666] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key localhost:80:0, check /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:21.111567 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3727] AH01906: localhost:80:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:21.111972 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3727] AH01909: localhost:80:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:21.163516 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3727] AH01906: localhost:80:1 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:21.163631 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3727] AH01909: localhost:80:1 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:21.168113 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3727] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate 127.0.0.1:443:0 (with chain), check /etc/ssl/certs/my-pubkey.perm
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:21.168237 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3727] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:21.168340 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3727] SSL Library Error: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:52.430593 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3797] AH01906: localhost:80:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:52.430987 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3797] AH01909: localhost:80:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:52.482936 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3797] AH01906: localhost:80:1 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:52.483046 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3797] AH01909: localhost:80:1 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:52.484628 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3797] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate 127.0.0.1:443:0 (with chain), check /etc/ssl/certs/my-pubkey.perm
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:52.484737 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3797] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Fri Jun 24 06:38:52.484838 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3797] SSL Library Error: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf` where SSL-key things and other settings, which can cause the complications

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIU
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key

SetEnvIf User-Agent .*MSIE.* nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log \
"%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

System: Raspbian Jessie
Storage system: ownCloud 8.2.5 on Apache
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3b

Comment: Lot's of information here, but what about your apache error logs? Also, `journalctl` and `systemctl status` lack information because you ran them as non-root.

Comment: Where is `/etc/ssl/certs/my-public-cert.pem`?

Comment: You seem to have a passphrase on your private key. Remove it.

Comment: @garethTheRed How can you remove the password on the private key? I just run the key commands again without entering any password. Actually, it did not ask any password in any stage. I get `Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-06-24 16:29:16 UTC; 12min ago
  Process: 4900 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2901 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4911 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)` from `sudo systemctl -l status apache2`. What do you think?

Comment: I think you've got a misconfigured Apache.  The first line of your `error.log` extract says incorrect key for `localhost:80`.  There should not be a key for port 80 as that is the HTTP port (as opposed to HTTPS). You might have extra `SSLCertificateKeyFile` somewhere in your configuration, which means it is looking for a different private key to the one you generated.

Comment: I had a mistake in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf` with wrong .crt file. I have SSL configs in two files: the former and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deflaut.conf`. The latter has only the three SSL lines at the beginning of the body, while the former has also configs. Still, I get the same error in `sudo systemctl -l status apache2`. What could be the next .log file to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@garethTheRed's comment solves the thing: `sudo systemctl -l status apache2` which gives clear logs (see the body of the question), and solve the case by correcting PATHs to private and public keys, `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/owncloud-ssl.conf` which however may be unsuitable for `ownCloud` because of no access still in http/https

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my-pubkey.perm
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
    DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I restart apache2 again and do

```
masi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl -l status apache2 
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-06-23 19:58:00 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 1280 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 23 19:58:00 raspberrypi apache2[1280]: Starting web server: apache2Action 'start' failed.
Jun 23 19:58:00 raspberrypi apache2[1280]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 23 19:58:00 raspberrypi apache2[1280]: .
Jun 23 19:58:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Output: http/https addresses do not work. Expected: they should work. Something other also wrong.

- Test 1. `ping 192.168.1.107` works so something wrong in directing the traffic

  ```
  PING 192.168.1.107 (192.168.1.107) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from 192.168.1.107: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.661 ms
  64 bytes from 192.168.1.107: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.653 ms
  ...
  ```

Do the appropriate changes also in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-ssl.conf` about `SSLCertificateFile` (certificate here, not public key) and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` (private key)

```
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
```

I had a public key by accident in the place of the certificate in the file. See the body for the complete file. Output: no access still in HTTP url. Expected output: access in HTTP.

Comment: This answer solves the original problem of an incorrect path to the keys.  However, you have another error.  Look at the Apache error logs, probably in `/var/logs/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: @garethTheRed Please, see the body of the question for the log. I get many times `AH00016: Configuration Failed`. What do you think? I have entered a few times password wrong. It is bad that it does not say when you type the passphrase wrong in the STOUT.